# How to Populate a List<string> in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Here's another easy XAML question for you guys:

I can populate a 'complex' list okay in XAML like:

```
<local:People x:Key="family">
    <local:Person Name="The Babe" Age="45"/>
    <local:Person Name="Greggles" Age="41"/>           
    <local:Person Name="Elmo" Age=10"/>
</local:People>
```

But in the case of:

```
public class FileNames : List<string> { }
```

...how are the strings added?

```
<local:FileNames x:Key="fileNames">
        ???
</local:FileNames>
```

BTW You may recongnise the example, adapted from "Programming WPF" by Chris Sells.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<local:FileNames x:Key="fileNames" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String>One</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
</local:FileNames>
```

Comment: I found that I need to add the prefix: clr-namespace: to the attribute value, as per @Konamiman's answer below

Answer (score 40):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx):

```
<x:Array Type="sys:String"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <sys:String>Hello</sys:String>
   <sys:String>World</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

I guess creatting a list instead of an array would be similar.

Comment: Beaten by 4 secs. Agh, too bad. But thanks for the reply. sys:String was indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: x:Array works in WPF. there is no such thing in Silverlight... nobody even reading these answers.. amazing

Comment: @BoppityBop what has Silverlight to do with this?

Comment: @Konamiman, that link es en Espanol. Mi comprehende Espanol muy poquito. I hope you understand at least.