# WPF Passing unknown number of strings to user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Okay so I have a user control which has a image url property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUrl", typeof(string), typeof(CoreGameTile));
public string ImageUrl
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageUrlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, value); }
        }
```

Now how would I go about passing multiple image urls without having know the exact number.

So sometimes I will have 5 image urls and other times I may have 2 or so. What would be a way to pass multiple image urls without knowing the exact amount.

I also would like to be able to use the XAML to add it like this

```
<Controls:CoreGameTile Width="200" Height="100" Margin="2" Title="Bink" ImageUrl="http://www.splashdamage.com/screens_brink/031.jpg"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Populate a List<string> in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508035/how-to-populate-a-liststring-in-xaml)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could pass it a `List` of `ImageUrl`'s and you can use a `foreach` loop to set each `ImageUrl` inside the List?

```
public string ImageUrl
{
    get { return (List<string>)GetValue(ImageUrlProperty); }
    set
    {
        foreach (ImageUrl url in value)
        {
            SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree. Change your `typeof(string)` to `typeof(List<string>)`.