# How to populate List<string> with StaticResource's strings

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml

in my WPF project in C# 4.0, in the resource dictionary I have string resources:

```
    <System:String x:Key="s_one">One</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="s_two">Two</System:String>
```

I want to use the strings above to populate a List of string Ls in xaml file.

```
    <cc:XYZ.Ls>   
       <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_one" />   
       <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_two" /> 
    </cc:XYZ.Ls>
```

This doesn't work. The detail in the exception says 
{"'One' is not a valid value for property 'Ls'."}

But, when I put another string before the those strings, it run nicely.

```
    <cc:XYZ.Ls>
      <System.String>Zero</System.String>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_one" />
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_two" />
    </cc:XYZ.Ls>
```

The items in Ls after running are { "Zero", "One", "Two" }

Is there a way of inserting strings from StaticResource into a list of string without adding the extra string in XAML?

Note: The relevant part of class XYZ:

```
    public partial class XYZ : UserControl
    {
         public static readonly DependencyProperty LsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Ls", typeof(List<string>), typeof(XYZ), 
                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

          public List<string> Ls
          {
             get { return (List<string>)GetValue(XYZ.LsProperty); }
             set { SetValue(XYZ.LsProperty, value); }
           }

          public XYZ()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              Ls = new List<string>();
          }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. Can you show us your `XYZ` class please... well, maybe *just the relevant parts*?

Comment: There's a bug in your code: `new List<string>()` instance from property metadata will be shared by **all** `XYZ` objects.

Comment: Thx, you are right. I didn't copy the constructor to the question above. Sorry.

Comment: my answer was not appropriate, so I deleted it. but isn't the dependency property supposed to be backed by a concrete variable. `Register("Ls"` should be the name of a `List<string> ls;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx) way

**But You can workaround like ...**

```
public class ArrayToListConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new List<string>();
        return ((string[]) value).ToList();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

```
 public partial class Xyz : UserControl
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Ls", typeof(List<string>), typeof(Xyz),
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public List<string> Ls
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(Xyz.LsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(Xyz.LsProperty, value); }
    }

    public Xyz()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
```

---

```
  <Window.Resources>

    <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="lst">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_one"/>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="s_two" />
    </x:Array>

     <wpfApplication2:ArrayToListConvertor x:Key="Conv"></wpfApplication2:ArrayToListConvertor>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <wpfApplication2:Xyz x:Name="Xyz" Ls="{Binding Path=., Source={StaticResource lst}, Converter={StaticResource Conv}}">

    </wpfApplication2:Xyz>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Xyz, Path=Ls }">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

---

Comment: The problem isn't with populating List<string> with System.String inserted directly to XAML. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508035/how-to-populate-a-liststring-in-xaml

The problem is with using strings taken from ResourceDictionary, which is also not entirely illegal (the second example above works).

Comment: Hi Dipak, thanks.. I just tried out your idea. The compiler run smoothly, but when I checked the content of Ls, it gave an empty list. It seemed that the binding never took place. Do you think we can actualy bind/apply an array of type System.String[] to a List<System.String>?

Comment: Its worth pasting the actual CODE, As it was fine with me though. There is nothing wrong in binding unless you are replacing some reference afterwards...Try it in NEW WPF project, Use Listbox, Bind ItemSource to List(array as above)...Prove yourself wrong, Its in your interest...  :)

Comment: Dipak, your solution works IF you do the binding to ListBox.ItemSource. The type of Items in the ListBox is System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection, not List<string>, although you could bind a List<string> to ListBox.Items. I have zipped the sample solution I used to test your idea. Do you know how I can attach a zip file to this comment?

Comment: Could anybody please explain why the second case in the question works, while the first case doesn't.

Comment: You see the String List coming through your control's (Xyz.LS) property(So binding works, It has to)....by the way, ListBox Items prop is readonly collection, which reflects the items currently ListBox having.... You can't bind it...one more, ListBox.ItemSource can take any IEnumerable...So on....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, you are right! Using the convertor solves the problem. Thanks Dipak!!