# How to Populate a List<object> in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I came to know the same thing for string using the link [How to Populate a List<string> in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508035/how-to-populate-a-liststring-in-xaml)

But need to do the same on object (say for string only)..

Answer (score -1):

Use the binding context to populate the list. Set the binding target as list object and binding source as the source of data.

Look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/) for example. I think it answers your question.